# vue-cli 3.0 - jsonpArray.push is undefined when the output library code splits

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I am writing a library with `vue` and using `vue-cli` 3.0-rc. I would like to use `vue-cli-service build --target lib` to build the library bundle.

It works fine if no split happens. However, if the result is big and webpack 4 needs to split it (to `abcd.umd.js` and `abcd.umd.0.js` I got the following error (on the page):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

Further investigation shows that the error is here:

```
var jsonpArray = typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : 
  this["webpackJsonpvue_sequence"] = typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : 
    this["webpackJsonpvue_sequence"] || [];
var oldJsonpFunction = jsonpArray.push.bind(jsonpArray);enter code here
```

`jsonpArray` is set to `window` and it does not have a `push` method.

I wonder if I can disable code splitting in webpack 4 or are there other options I can look into.

Comment: I have made some progress, just sharing here. The code split has been caused by `import('./some-component')` not due to size as I thought.

Comment: I think I may find a bug. An issue has been created here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1607 (with reproduction repos).

Answer (score 0):

If you come here for any kind of solution, you can disable code splitting by

```
components: { 'block': () => import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */ './Block.vue') }
```

For more information: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-